# Updating values in Dataframe in a certain number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a dataframe

```
d={'Col1':['a','b','c','e','f','g','a','b','c','d'],'Col2':[3,4,6,None,7,8,None,9,None,None,]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

what I need is to set values where Col2 is equal NaN:
first three = 100

normally I would use loc for such tasks but for reasons I don't understand it does not work with loc+iloc:

```
df.loc[df.Col2.isnull()].iloc[:3]=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with parameter `limit`:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].fillna(100, limit=3)
print (df)
  Col1   Col2
0    a    3.0
1    b    4.0
2    c    6.0
3    e  100.0
4    f    7.0
5    g    8.0
6    a  100.0
7    b    9.0
8    c  100.0
9    d    NaN
```

If want use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) get first 3 indices of `NaN`s and set value:

```
idx = df.index[df.Col2.isnull()]
df.loc[idx[:3], 'Col2'] = 100
```